# Understanding meaning of polar

Tags: geometry

If $ A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n $, one can define the polar
$$ A^\circ=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\mid \forall y\in A \ \langle x,y\rangle\le 1 \}, $$
where $ \langle x,y\rangle $ is scalar product.

What's the meaning of this definition? Is there any way to easily calculate $ A^\circ $ for some well-known sets, like ball, plane, etc.?